# Rails - validates_associated not working with presence validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, activerecord

I am trying to validate presence of `:picture` on a `user_items` model in a nested form.

**item.rb**

```
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  has_many :user_items, inverse_of: :item
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :user_items
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_items
  validates_associated :user_items
```

**user_item.rb**

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item, inverse_of: :user_items
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :picture, presence: true
  validate :picture_size
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @item.user_items.build
  end

  def create
    @item = item.new item_params

    if @item.save
      redirect_to items_path, notice: "Thank you for your item request!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :tag_list, user_items_attributes: [:picture]).merge(created_by: current_user.id)
    end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @item, html: { class: "create-item-form" } do |item_builder| %>
  <div class="well">
  <%= item_builder.input :name, required: false, error: false, label: "Item name" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :description, as: :text, required: false, error: false, label: "Description of item" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :tag_list, required: false, label: "Tags (these will help users find your item)" %>
  <%= item_builder.simple_fields_for :user_items do |user_item_builder| %>
    <%= user_item_builder.input :picture, as: :file, required: false, label: "Picture of you with this item" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= item_builder.submit 'Submit new item request', class: "btn btn-primary pull-right inherit-width" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is not working.  I submit a blank form and only the name and description validations trigger.

Update:

Oddly enough it seems the validation will work if I add a hidden_field to my form for the user_id:

```
<%= user_item_builder.input :user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: current_user.id } %>
```

What is going on here?

Update2:

The validation also seems to work if I change the create action:

```
  def create
    @item = item.new item_params
    @item.user_items.build
    if @item.save
      redirect_to items_path, notice: "Thank you for your item request!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Why do I need to add `@item.user_items.build`?  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: you try removing the ```required: false``` that you have on the pic part of the form?

Comment: Yes, thats just part of the simple_form for plugin

Comment: @MilesStanfield `required: false` just makes it so that the input does not have a HTML5 `required` attribute that is used for client side validation. It does not effect the server at all.

Comment: Can you try doing some debugging to narrow it down? Do `UserItem.create.errors` from the console. If it has the key `:picture` then the error is not in the UserItem model.

Comment: If you do `User.create(user_items_attributes: {}).errors.full_messages` it should have something like "user_items is invalid"

Comment: @max Do you mean `Item.create`?

Comment: Yes, `Item.create`, sorry

Comment: I just get `=> ["Name can't be blank", "Description can't be blank"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103449/discussion-between-max-and-user4584963).